# Remove first 4 letters from a folder name using Bash scripting

Tags: python, linux, bash

As the title says I want to remove the first 4 letters from a folder name using a [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash) script. If you have another way to do it in Linux I don't really mind e.g. Python. Also I need the script to be executed regularly (daily).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way in Bash:

```
$ dname=mydirectory
$ echo ${dname:4}
rectory
```

Comment: I have to test this first but that looks way to easy :)

Comment: It should be mentioned for completeness that this parameter expansion is not ISO9945, mine is. If you stick with Bash or Korn, there shouldn't be a problem. But you should never use a #!/bin/sh Shebang when not using ISO constructs.

Comment: Sort of, yes. POSIX, if you like. In XCU, it's the same.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't mention to rename a directory or so, I assume you want simple string editing. If you want more, you should ask the right questions.

```
# name of the DIRECTORY (not ''folder''...)
name=fooodir

# compute a new name
editedname=${name#????}
echo "${editedname}"
```

Comment: Ah, missed the daily execution thing: Check your cron related manpages.